# How do I properly make images for a website?

Tags: html, image, xhtml, colors

I know this seems like a simple question, but I'm really stuck. I am developing a website and Firefox is altering the image colors for the site.  The issue is stemming from Firefox's use of ICC color profiles (I think).

I've done tons of research on the topic, and most of it boils down to sRGB when saving in Photoshop, but the color profiles are already set to sRGB.

These are the color settings I use when I save:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLJ5g.png

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAx88.png - How it looks in Firefox 3, Chrome, and IE
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7bcC.png - How it looks in Firefox 4

I can disable Firefox 4's color management through

`about:config / gfx.color_management.enabled = 0`,

but that is not a correct solution.

Wat do?

URL: http://development.smgwebdesign.com/riley

Thanks guys.

Comment: This is a design question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Diodeus not really. It's a browser colour management question that is much, much more suitable here with other HTML/CSS questions than it is on graphicDesign.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to help keep the colours correct, don't use an image to create the background.
As it is only one colour just set the background colour using css.
It accepts hexidecimal values.
eg #15253c would be your colour.
You can find different ones in photoshop by going to the colour selector tool.
It shows what the colour is in lots of different ways.

Then make the background of the logo transparent so there are no colour issues there.
I can't see how you're colouring the nav menu, but if you can use css and background colours directly,
as apposed to images, it will work better.
Use css wherever you can, it will work better and your website will load faster.
Check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp for help with CSS.
Also, for the images you do have to use, try the 'save for web' option in photoshop.

Comment: Oh yeah, I am using #15253c as the color for both the background of the stylesheet and the image background.  I've already mapped out the right colors.  It's only a Firefox thing.  I don't know what FF is doing differently than chrome or IE.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue, which has to do with different handling of colour profiles in different browsers.

Comment: I think I see what he's suggesting, Pekka, which is a hack that would indeed (or should) work.  basically instead of  using blue for the BG in the image, make it totally transparent, allowing the actual div BG to show through.

Comment: Though it is strange as for me, the website displays the same in FF4, IE9, Safari5, and Chrome. So maybe it is your version of FF.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit out of my depth because I haven't been a Photoshop user for a long time, but the general solution to this is not to  embed a ICC colour profile in the first place.

You should have a check box for that in your export dialog. Is that already turned off?

Comment: @MALON ah, it doesn't seem to be embedding a profile at all. Strange.